# Accepting api keys in HTTP headers or JSON POST data

Tags: rest, request, django-views, authorization, httprequest

I have an HTTP JSON endpoint `localhost:8000/resource/` that takes JSON data as input and returns JSON as output. I am now adding `API Key` based authorization to the endpoint. There are 2 ways to accept the `API Key` at this endpoint:

#### Method A: In the request headers

Example python code:

```
import requests
headers = {
   'API-Key': '<my-api-key>',
}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/resource/',
                   json={'input': <value>}, 
                   headers=headers)
```

#### Method B: In the JSON data itself

Example python code:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/resource/', 
                   json={'input': <value>, 'API-Key': '<my-api-key>'},)
```

I usually notice **Method A** being adopted. Is there anything wrong with latter approach in which the API key is passed along with the other json data?

Comment: https://blog.stoplight.io/api-keys-best-practices-to-authenticate-apis: "The most significant drawback to this method is that authentication is mixed in with other data. It also encourages poor REST practices, as simple reads from the API would need to be sent a POST request instead of GET."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with clarity, the API Key isn't really relevant to the input, it's just a form of authorization.

Large frameworks that deal with routing and such are able to filter based on specific headers, and it would be cumbersome to filter based off of a specific form of input in the request body that would require user to intervene and obtain that value for it. Headers are simpler, and suffice for simple data that would fit in a hash-table.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it makes sense. Though I am still looking for more convincing answers with explanations and citations to RFCs.